# Finding a function without knowing its structure but some conditions

Tags: calculus, analysis, functions

I'm trying to find a function who meets this conditions but have no idea where to start. Just think it may be related to the function $Ca^{-\left(x-\mu\right)^2}$, If it really has this structure (or not), just imagine we want to know who is $f$ without predicting it's structure but knowing:

1) $\int_0^\infty f(x)dx=1$

2) $\frac{d}{dx}f(\mu)=0, \mu\in\mathbb{R^+}$

3) $f(x)=f(2\mu-x)$

4)$f(x)\ge0, [0,\infty)$

Comment: For 2, $f(\mu)$ does not depend on $x$, so it is automatic.  Maybe you mean $\frac d{dx}f(x)|_u$?

Comment: lol Have never seen $\frac{d}{dx}f(x)|_\mu$, but if it means "derivate f and then evaluate it with $\mu$", then yes, it's what I mean. @RossMillikan

Comment: That is exactly what it means.

Answer (score 0):

Take any function $g$ on $[\mu, \infty)$ such that $g \ge 0$, $g'(\mu) = 0$ and $\int_\mu^\infty g(x)\; dx < \infty$, define $g$ on $(-\infty,\mu)$ by $g(x) = g(2\mu - x)$, then let $f(x) = g(x)/\left(\int_{0}^\infty g(t)\ dt\right)$.